# How to generate Jacoco.exec in command line?

Tags: java, jacoco

I have to generate coverage report for simple java application(No maven/ant) by using jacoco. To do this, downloaded jar files for jacoco and put it in library folder. I want to use jacococli.jar for report generation, but before that need to figure out how to generate jacoco.exec data.

So far I have tried this,

Used following command to generate Jacoco.exec ([by following jacoco doc](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/agent.html))

```
    java -javaagent:./jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=output=file,destfile=./target/jacoco.exec,includes=./bin/*,append=true
```

bin/ contains my .class files.

The issue is, it is always generating an empty jacoco.exec file. What are the prerequisites for getting data into this? Currently I am just giving my .class file path in the command(./bin).

Apart from 'file' option in javaagent, read about tcpserver and tcpclient options in jacoco documentation. If I want to use tcpserver option what are the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the prerequisites for getting data into this?

You need to run your code, JaCoCo will instrument classes at bytecode level and record code paths hit by run of your code.

This is normally done by invoking unit tests with attached javaagent.

Comment: Thank you, have one more doubt. I have a bat file to run the code, javac -d bin/ ./src/*.java 
javac -d bin/ ./specs/*.java
java TestRunner. So should I run the above command while running this?

Comment: `java TestRunner` - this is where you want to attach javaagent